# Retrieve an ExtJS element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Do not mind if you consider this as a silly question !

I've created a button with ExtJS

```
{
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Test',
id: 'test007',
scale: 'small',
margin: '5 0 5 0',
}
```

Is there a way to get reference to this object in the HTML code ?

I've tried

```
    <div id="test007">
        <script>
        $('#test007').click(function(){
            alert('click')
        });
        </script>
    </div>
```

but doesn't work (maybe with a class instead of an id ?).

I don't know if I'm clear enough or even if my question makes sense.
You could say that "What is the point to use jQuery function when you can trigger function like click directly in ExtJS", but my real aim is not to trigger jQuery stuff in HTML.

I want to add some server side code to the HTML file then pre-processing it before render.

I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks !

Comment: Do not mix JQuery with ExtJS - it will lead to an awful mess. Learn to use ExtJS instead - you will be productive once you do, I promise. On SO ask questions like: "How do I disable button in Ext after it was rendered." You will get great answers.

Comment: Thanks, I am alright with JS and ExtJS, I can disable a button after it was render ^^. As I said the main point was not to use jQuery stuff because I am aware it's not recommended to use several JS libraries in the same page. I guess I'm going to fulfill my needs using private function in JavaScript. Because my point was : if you disable a button because the user can't access it, without security he can still re-able it using a browser console.

Comment: This is true of all JS. You cannot rely on the client for security. What is your real question?

Comment: We have an web application we made for a client. First, there was no need to login to access the app, but the now the client wants ones. Problem, app has never been designed to do so. For example we have a header with 5 buttons. A "x" user can only see 4 buttons (that's what the client wants). As I am using twig to render the page, I though if I could access the button through html, I could do some {%  if %} to display the button or not from the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that jQuery's click even doesn't directly correspond to that from ExtJS. If you inspect the DOM, you'll find that ExtJS components are usually complex compared to a simple `<button/>` type and thus you really need to stick to ExtJS event handlers for this sort of thing.

Based on what you're doing, it's also not even obvious that your code is even working at all since you're just using a XType declaration with no code that's obviously rendering it somewhere. This is the ExtJS 3 approach to render to that `<div/>`

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Test',
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            alert('Hi!');
        }
    },
    renderTo: 'test007',
    scale: 'small',
    margin: '5 0 5 0'
});
```

That also needs to run on ready like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //That code here
});
```

Or

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

});
```

Comment: Ok I get your point. The main issue is that someone already created a full ExtJS app, and now I have to display -or not buttons according to the user connected. So I though I could do it like this :(